# How to define class for Trie in cpp

Tags: c++, trie

Hi I am new to oops in cpp. I define a class for trie Node as follows. But I get this error and I couldnot find where I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

> Error : Line 5: expected identifier before numeric constant

```
class Node {
        public:
            bool end;
            char val;
            vector<Node *> children(26);
        Node(char val)
        {
            val=val;
            end=false;
            for(i=0;i<children.size();i++)
                children[i]=NULL;
        }
};
```

Comment: Either use `vector<Node *> children{26};` or `vector<Node *> children = vector<Node *>(26);`, or use member init list, as user0042 suggests.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should be

```
     vector<Node *> children;
Node(char val) : end(false), val('\0'), children(26)
{
    // ...
```

Use the member initializer list to call specific member variable constructors.

Comment: What if I have multiple vectors ? Say children1 and children2 ?

Comment: You can separate the constructor calls with comma then `children1(26), children2(43), ...`

Comment: Great ! Thanks alot :D